# How do I stop the category from getting pushed up whenever I display the subcategory?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, tailwind-css, nested-lists

I have 4 categories in a form of a list; All, Urbanism,Architecture, and Interior Design. Urbanism,Architecture, and Interior Design all have subcategories in a form of a list. The code both filters the images and displays subactegories. The problem that I have is that whenever I click on Urbanism, Architecture, or Interior Design to display the subcategories; the whole block gets pushed up.

I want all Urbanism, All, Architecture, and Interior Design to stay all on the same horiziontal line even when i click on any category to show the subcategories. I want the subcategories to be below its parent category when i click on it. Your help would be appreciated.Below is my code:

```
    <div class="about_section">
      <br />
      <h1>projects</h1>
      <ul class="switcher">
        <li data-cat=".all" class="active">All</li>
        <li data-cat=".urb" id="show">
          Urbanism

          <ul class="switcher" id="content" style="display: none">
            <li data-cat=".cityscale">City Scale</li>

            <li data-cat=".residential">Residential</li>
            <li data-cat=".entertainment">Entertainment</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-cat=".arch" id="showarch">
          Architecture
          <ul class="switcher" id="contentarch" style="display: none">
            <li data-cat=".adminstrative">Adminstrative</li>
            <li data-cat=".commercial">Commercial</li>
            <li data-cat=".hospitality">Hospitality</li>
            <li data-cat=".residential">Residential</li>
            <li data-cat=".educational">Educational</li>
            <li data-cat=".cultural">Cultural</li>
            <li data-cat=".entertainment">Entertainment</li>
            <li data-cat=".medical">Medical</li>
            <li data-cat=".religious">Religious</li>
            <li data-cat=".restoration">Restoration</li>
            <li data-cat=".infrastructure">Infrastructure</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-cat=".int" id="showint">
          Interior Design
          <ul class="switcher" id="contentint" style="display: none">
            <li data-cat=".residential">Residential</li>
            <li data-cat=".commercial">Commercial</li>
            <li data-cat=".cultural">Cultural</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
let switcherLi = document.querySelectorAll(".switcher li");
let imgs = Array.from(document.images);

switcherLi.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", removeActive);
  li.addEventListener("click", filter);
});

function removeActive() {
  switcherLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
}

function filter() {
  imgs.forEach((img) => {
    if (!img.classList.contains("logo")) {
      img.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.cat).forEach((el) => {
    el.style.display = "block";
  });
}

var urbanismElement = document.getElementById("show");
var contentElement = document.getElementById("content");

urbanismElement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === urbanismElement) {
    if (contentElement.style.display === "none") {
      contentElement.style.display = "block";
      archcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide architecture subcategories
      intcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide interior design subcategories
    } else {
      contentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

var archelement = document.getElementById("showarch");
var archcontent = document.getElementById("contentarch");

archelement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === archelement) {
    if (archcontent.style.display === "none") {
      archcontent.style.display = "block";
      contentElement.style.display = "none"; // Hide urbanism subcategories
      intcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide interior design subcategories
    } else {
      archcontent.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

var intelement = document.getElementById("showint");
var intcontent = document.getElementById("contentint");

intelement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === intelement) {
    if (intcontent.style.display === "none") {
      intcontent.style.display = "block";
      contentElement.style.display = "none"; // Hide urbanism subcategories
      archcontent.style.display = "none"; // Hide architecture subcategories
    } else {
      intcontent.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};

var allElement = document.querySelector('.switcher li[data-cat=".all"]');
var categoryElements = document.querySelectorAll(".switcher li[data-cat]");

allElement.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === allElement) {
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryElements.length; i++) {
      categoryElements[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    allElement.classList.add("active");
    contentElement.style.display = "none";
    archcontent.style.display = "none";
    intcontent.style.display = "none";
  }
};
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Advent+Pro&family=Amatic+SC&family=Bricolage+Grotesque:opsz@10..48&family=Cardo&family=Comfortaa:wght@300&family=Domine&family=Gruppo&family=Indie+Flower&family=Kodchasan:wght@300;500&family=Lato&family=Oswald&family=Playfair+Display+SC&family=Playfair+Display:wght@500&family=Roboto:wght@100&family=Rubik:ital,wght@1,300&family=Syncopate:wght@400;700&family=Urbanist&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "laluxesserifw05-regularRg";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "MADEMirage-Thin";
  src: url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.woff") format("woff"),
    url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.svg#MADEMirage-Thin") format("svg"),
    url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.eot"),
    url("MADEMirage-Thin.ttf.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
  font-family: "made_miragethin";
}
section {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar-nav {
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 0.5 1em;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: Regular;
}
.about_section {
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.about_section h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  --s: 150px; /* control the size */
  --g: 10px; /* control the gap */
  --f: 1.5; /* control the scale factor */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--g);
  width: calc(7 * var(--s) + 6 * var(--g));
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
.gallery > a {
  display: contents;
}
.gallery img {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: grayscale(80%);
  transition: 0.35s linear;
}

.gallery img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  width: calc(var(--s) * var(--f));
  height: calc(var(--s) * var(--f));
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.large {
    display: none;
  }
}

/***** for mobiles *****/

@media (min-width: 699px) {
  .cont {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 699px) {
  div.small {
    display: none;
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.grid img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}
.grid div {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.switcher {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  
  }
  
  .switcher li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  font-size: 12px;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  }

  
  .content div {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/g8392uo7/ - CSS only: `.switcher .switcher { position: absolute; z-index: 9999; }`

Comment: @GrafiCode Yes! Exactly, like that! But is there a way where I can make them below the parent and aligned horizontally and centered below it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/drLgb7jk/ changes (CSS) are for elements `.switcher` and `.switcher .switcher`

Comment: @GrafiCode Thank you so much! The horizontal alignnment has worked. There's only one thing that I can't quite figure out. I don't know how to align them below their parents. I want to  make them give the effect that they belong to their parent category.Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: mmm that's not as easy as it might seem. This example shows the "classic" vertical menu: https://jsfiddle.net/agzh1pnL/   when adding `width: 300px` (arbitrary width) and `left: -100px` (again, arbitrary value) it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/agzh1pnL/1/ which could be what you need, but keep in mind if a parent category has a long name, this trick won't work anymore

Comment: hopefully, somebody with more experience in CSS could post a proper answer to this

Comment: https://big.dk/ See it for reference . Thank You @GrafiCode

Comment: @GrafiCode I like the first onee Thank you so much , I tried it annd this is eexactly what I want!!!!! This is thee asnweer. How do you changee thee style of the parent when selected to have a bullet poinnt though, to show that it's selected?

Comment: `.switcher li.active { your-style }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this problem is related to php, it is more of a css issue if I understood correctly. Anyways you have an extra css rule for the .switcher class. Just comment out the align-items center and it is working.

```
    .switcher {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
    list-style: none;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 10px 10px;    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.There's only one problem, I don't know how to center the subcetgories below the main category.

Comment: I wannt it like the website : https://big.dk/